# SAP BO How to set Maximum Character Stream Size (MB) and Binary Stream Maximum Size (MB)

Tags: business-objects

we need to increase these two parameters: 
Maximum Character Stream Size (MB)
Binary Stream Maximum Size (MB)
in Business objects for WebIntelligenceProcessingServer due to following error:
[image]

I know how to get there, but I'm not able to set it because it's shown as checkbox (please see following picture).
[image]

Please have someone met this problem or does anyone know how to set/fix it?

Thank you in advance.
Best Regards,
Martin

Comment: My two systems (XI3.1 SP7 and BI4.1 SP06) both have an entry field and no checkbox.  It's possible that it may be a bug with the specific version you're on.  What happens if you check the boxes, save changes, and go back in?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I get following error when trying to save them checked: The argument has an invalid value setValue(): Invalid value or value out of valid range.

Comment: Yeah, something is screwy with the server.  If you create a new WebI processing server, do you see the same behavior?  You might need to open an incident with SAP.

Comment: Are you experiencing the same behaviour (checkbox instead of input field in CMC) across different browsers (e.g. IE, Chrome, Firefox)? Even with add-ons disabled?